# Regex search is very slow inside a loop using python

Tags: python, regex

I have found a strange thing

```
for el in values:
    unit=re.search(regex_unit, el, re.IGNORECASE).group()
    value=re.search(regex_value, el, re.IGNORECASE).group()
    print("Unit: "+unit+" - "+"Value: "+value)
```

this code is very slow but if I write it in this way it is super fast...

```
for el in values:
    unit=re.search(regex_unit, el, re.IGNORECASE).group()
    print("Unit: "+unit)
for el in values:
    value=re.search(regex_value, el, re.IGNORECASE).group()
    print("Value: "+value)
```

What's wrong with the first piece od code?

*** UPDATE

```
regex_unit="(kb|mb|gb)"
regex_value="\d"
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about your statement "super fast"??

Comment: As an aside, why you don't build a pattern that gets unit and value at the same time. And why you don't compile it before the loop?

Comment: Can you add your regex to question? and explain more about the speed difference?

Comment: Is the result the same? Is `values` a generator by any chance?

Comment: I have added the regex

Comment: I don't see any difference, both pieces perform similarly, what did you use to benchmark/profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For regex, generally, I would recommend to compile them.

This answer of course does not answer the question, how the speed difference comes. But one guess of mine is, that the Python runtime does just that:

If it has to execute a regex, it compiles it and caches the result. If it runs inside a loop with no other regex (like in your second code), the cached version is used. But if it alternates with other regexes, the cached version is always overwritten and has to be created again always, what would reduce the speed dramatically, because the compilation step has to be done again and again.

You can bypass the problem by doing the compilation yourself, like that:

```
regex_unit_compiled = re.compile(regex_unit)
```

After that, use it in the loop like that:

```
unit=regex_unit_compiled.search(el, re.IGNORECASE).group()
```

If my guess is right or not, with compiled regexes you should be better off.

Comment: Can you post an example of how can I precompile them?

Comment: It does not seem to clean the cache, unless it overgrows 512 entries, [see the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/re.py#L278)

Comment: @bereal: Thanks for the research. The code really looks so, that my guess does not hold. It was a guess of course from me and there could be other factors working into it, without more information it is really difficult to decide. One is the Python version. There must be some explanation for the speed difference -- but it is difficult to say, without exact numbers.